# How to Cancel Subscription created thought Checkout Session Stripe API

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I have created a recurring product on stripe, and creating a checkout session and it's working fine and creating a subscription for me that i can see on the dashboard.

this is my code

```
        checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
            success_url=domain_url + 'success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
            cancel_url=domain_url + 'cancelled/',
            payment_method_types=['card'],
            mode='subscription',
            line_items=[
                {
                    'quantity': 1,
                    'price': 'price_1HLDRqCHEV6ur4mXq36yVF1D',
                }
            ]
        )
```

I want to provide a facility to user that they can cancle their subscription that they have made through checkout session, but it can be cancelled through subscription id only, but i am not getting any subscription id from the checkout session.

How can i allow the user to cancle their subscription that they made through checkout session ?

Answer (score 3):

When you create a subscription using Stripe Checkout, the subscription will only be created and available after your user's have gone through the Checkout flow. What this means is that when you initially create the Checkout Session the session object's [subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-checkout.session.completed) property will be `null`.

As soon as your user's complete the checkout flow, Stripe will emit a [checkout.session.completed](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-checkout.session.completed) event containing the newly created subscription ID which you can use to cancel the subscription. To listen for these events you need to create a webhook endpoint, which is really no different than creating any other HTTP endpoint on your site. Here are some examples that you can reference:

- https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders
- https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/integration-builder

Once you have an endpoint setup to listen for the [checkout.session.completed](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-checkout.session.completed) event. Stripe will send the updated session object (with the subscription ID) in the [event data](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/object?lang=python#event_object-data-object). From there you can save the subscription ID to your database to reference later. If your user's want to cancel the subscription you would need to call this API endpoint here:

https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/cancel?lang=python

Another simpler option would be to use the new Customer Portal which would save you from having to create a UI for your users to upgrade/cancel your existing subscriptions. Simply provide the customer's ID as shown in this guide here:

https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/integrating-customer-portal